# Is there a better way to set a Read-Write property than with WhenAnyValue and BindTo?

Tags: c#, mvvm, reactive-programming, reactiveui

I have a read-write property

```
    private string _serialNumber;
    public string SerialNumber
    {
        get => _serialNumber;
        set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _serialNumber, value);
    }
```

that I need to update when a `Product` property changes. I use `WhenAnyValue` and `BindTo` for this purpose.

```
this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.Product)
            .Where(x => x != null)
            .Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault())
            .BindTo(this, x => x.SerialNumber);
```

However, I'm not sure if this is the best approach because I'm not able to find any example where read-write property is updated using `WhenAnyValue`.

Is there a better solution? Do I use read-write property incorrectly in this case?

Comment: Can you just store Product as a property and use it directly?

Comment: I think that I don't understand your comment. Product is a property already and when it's updated I want to make an action.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Observable As Property Helper](https://reactiveui.net/docs/guidelines/framework/prefer-oaph-over-properties) to set the value of a property in the view model. you then want to bind to the view.

```
ObservableAsPropertyHelper<string> _serialNumber;

public string SerialNumber => _serialNumber.Value;

_serialNumber = this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.Product)
        .Where(x => x != null)
        .Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault()).ToProperty(this, x => SerialNumber);
```

Then just bind the View to ViewModel.SerialNumber

Comment: What you suggest is an output property pattern, but I need read-write property since my view also sets the value of the property.

Comment: Your view sets the value of which property? Product or SerialNumber?